# Using different features for the same estimator in the pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-selection

I have a nice pipeline that does the following:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("first transformer", ct),
    ("second transformer", OHE),
    ('standard_scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
    ("logistic regression", estimator)
])
```

The estimator part is this:

```
estimator = MultiOutputClassifier(
    estimator = LogisticRegression(penalty="l2", C=2)
)
```

Label DataFrame is of shape (1000, 2) and all works nicely so far.

To tweak the model I now try to add SelectKBest to limit the features used for calculations. Unfortunately adding this code to the pipeline:

```
('feature_selection', SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=9))
```

returns this error:

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (20030, 2) instead.
```

I understand where it comes from and using only one label (1000, 1) solves the issue but that means I would need to create two separate pipelines for each label.

Is there any way of including feature selection in this pipeline without resorting to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want (potentially) to use a different subset of features for each output, you should just put the `SelectKBest` in a pipeline with the `LogisticRegression` *inside* the `MultiOutputClassifier`.

```py
clf = Pipeline([
    ("feature_selection", SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=9)),
    ("logistic regression", LogisticRegression(penalty="l2", C=2)),
])
estimator = MultiOutputClassifier(clf)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("first transformer", ct),
    ("second transformer", OHE),
    ('standard_scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
    ("select_and_model", estimator),
])
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was that easy...
I understand this code will take k=9 best features for each label separately and that is great.
I'm having another issue now and that is: I'd like to use different number of k features for each label. I have a code returning number of k values over certain threshold but what it does with a 2d labels array is running through all of them at once instead of returning separate value for each column.
Can it be done in any way in the pipeline without creating separate pipeline for each label?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I know it would be simpler to abandon MultiOutputClassifier approach and use LabelBinarizer to have 1D labels array instead. But what I need in the end are the probabilities and not binary labels. From what I understand Keras does this but I'm not yet familiar with it.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to have different pipelines for the different outputs in `MultiOutputClassifier`, no.  With completely separate pipelines for each output, you can still get probabilities for each target.  Your preprocessing could still be done as a single object.  If you really want one object (and you'll do this repeatedly), you could maybe modify the `MultiOutputClassifier` class to take separate preprocessing pipes, or the `SelectKBest` class to work for multi-target data.